# Photon creates a new room for each player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have written my Photon script so that the player joins a random room, and if no room is found, the player will automatically create a new room. However, when I build and run my game on two different computers, no room is found on both of them, so they both create their own room. Please can someone tell me why?

The game starts like it should when there only 1 player is required, but when 2 are required it doesn't, because of the issue I mentioned above.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkManager : Photon.PunBehaviour
{

public string playerprefabname = "player";
Vector3 spawner = new Vector3(9.9f, -3.8f, -0.1f);


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    //Log stuff to console
    PhotonNetwork.logLevel = PhotonLogLevel.Full;

    //Connect
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("v0.1");

    //Sync scenes
    PhotonNetwork.automaticallySyncScene = true;

}

//Display connection state on game
void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString());
}


public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
}

public override void OnJoinedLobby()
{
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
}

//Create a room if fail to join one
void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed()
{
    Debug.Log("Can't join random room!");
    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions() { isVisible = false, maxPlayers = 2 };
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null, roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default);
}

// when joined to a room check if 3 players are there, then send to level
public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.playerList.Length == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("2 Players In Room Starting Level");

        GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerprefabname, spawner, spawnpoint.rotation, 0);

        //GameObject MyCam = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Camera", CamPos, Quaternion.identity, 0);
        GameObject camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");

        if (camera != null)
        {
            CameraController followScript = camera.GetComponent("CameraController") as CameraController;
            if (followScript != null)
            {
                followScript.target = myPlayer;
            }
        }

    }
}

public override void OnPhotonPlayerConnected(PhotonPlayer newPlayer)
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.playerList.Length == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("2 Players In Room Starting Level");

        GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerprefabname, spawner, spawnpoint.rotation, 0);

        //GameObject MyCam = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Camera", CamPos, Quaternion.identity, 0);
        GameObject camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");

        if (camera != null)
        {
            CameraController followScript = camera.GetComponent("CameraController") as CameraController;
            if (followScript != null)
            {
                followScript.target = myPlayer;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The reason is isVisible option set to false when you create the room. 
Because of that room is not shown in room list and can not be chosen by random join.

Answer (score 0):

were the computers connected to each other like via LAN or wireless-ly? it creates a room when there is no connection between the two computers.

Comment: Both computers are connected to the same internet (one by an ethernet cable and the other wirelessly)

Comment: you should make an option to "Host a game" and "Join the game" because it will not search automatically unless both the computers are joined either via LAN or both via wireless-ly. So make two options for Hosting a game and joining a game.. Hosting will enable the player to host a game so that his/ her friend can directly join the game and vice versa for joining. Not sure about the codes, but try making those two options.

Comment: But how my game works is someone clicks 'Play multiplayer' then it will just match them up with opponents over the internet, then when 4 players are in the room, the game will start, so is this not possible?

Comment: You want some sort of matchmaking? Have you checked if the computers can comunicate without issues? are all required ports open?

Comment: This isn't local, the players are connecting to the photon server so I don't know why doesn't work